# cxFreeze and Jaraco: ImportError

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create an IRC client using the irclib library.  When I try to freeze the script using cxFreeze, however, I always run into that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "client.py", line 38, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jaraco
```

The setup.py script has been modified several times, to try to include files, packages and so on.  Nothing seems to work.  Here's the current version for reference:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

client = Executable(
    script="client.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
)

setup(
    name = "client",
    version = "0.2",
    description = "client",
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes': ["jaraco"], "packages": ["jaraco"]}},
    executables = [client],
)
```

The script of the client can be shortened in a single line:

```
from irc import client
```

That's all.  I'm not using Jaraco, irclib (package irc) is.  Jaraco must have been installed as a dependency from irclib.

I've tried to find the reasons why it could happen, but so far, nothing found.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide the script client.py? And the version of this jaraco that you are using?

Comment: @Tuininga: I'm only importing irc (I edited the post).  I don't use Jaraco, but irclib does.  I guess it was treated as a dependency when I installed irclib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some digging around, it seems the same problem exists with zope when freezing an application with twisted.  Although I haven't tested it with jaraco, I would imagine it's the same issue.  I hope this solution works for users stuck with the same problem:

1. In your 'site-packages' directory, in the 'jaraco' package, add the '**init**.py' file.  It can be empty.  Why isn't it provided, I have no idea.  A package without a '**init**.py", for cxFreeze, isn't a package.
2. Re-run the 'setup.py' script.  Don't include 'jaraco' as a package, provide the package that needs it (here, it would be 'irc').

Here's the setup.py script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

client = Executable(
    script="client.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
)

setup(
    name = "client",
    version = "0.2",
    description = "client",
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages': ["irc"]}},
    executables = [client],
)
```

I provide this answer because it worked just fine with twisted and zope.  Seeing my client uses twisted now for its IRC communication, I don't know if the provided steps below work, but that's what helped me for twisted.

HTH,